# Android Studio emulator 33 process not terminating macOS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Since Android Studio Flamingo (2022.2.1) in M1 pro, I am noticing when I close the emulator running API 33, the process id **qemu-system-aarch64** keeps running in the background (for hours!), which I found in the activity monitor.

It also appears as running in the IDE device manager window, and when I try to stop it, the following message is displayed.

> Error running 'app'
> Pixel 4 API 33 is already running. If that is not the case, delete
> /Users/$$/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_33.avd/* lock and try again.

I can forcefully stop/kill the process, but this annoying. Is there any permanent solution to this?